# Problema con tabla bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Buenas tengo un problema de css en una tabla  bootstrap cuando lleno con varios caracteres la columna Diagnostico las columnas son fechas se hacen mas pequeñas por lo que muestran las fechas cortadas nesecito que las columnas con fecha queden de forma estatica sin que se encojan para que su fecha siempre se muestre bien[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí], este es el codigo.

```
 <table id="userss" class="table table-striped table-bordered table condensed table-hover table-responsive " >
            <thead>

        <th>Id</th>
        <th >Dias</th>
        <th>A/P Fecha</th>
        <th>Fecha Cumple</th>
        <th>Diagnostico/Observaciones</th>
        <th>Medico</th>
        <th>Tipo</th>
        <th>Acciones</th>


            </thead>







     </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo utilizas DataTables. Existe una opción específica que es [columns.width](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width) que puedes utilizar de la siguiente forma:

```
$('#mi-tabla').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { "width": "20%", "targets": 0 },
    { "width": "60%", "targets": 1 },
    { "width": "20%", "targets": 2 }
  ]
} );
```

Ahí puedes especificar el ancho de cada columna.

Answer (score -1):

Aplicandole un `width` fijo con css se puede lograr:

```css
.table th.fixed-width {
    min-width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<table id="userss" class="table table-striped table-bordered table condensed table-hover table-responsive " >
       <thead>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Dias</th>
        <th class="fixed-width">A/P Fecha</th>
        <th class="fixed-width">Fecha Cumple</th>
        <th>Diagnostico/Observaciones</th>
        <th Medico</th>
        <th>Tipo</th>
        <th>Acciones</th>
      </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>
      22
    </td>
    <td>
      12
    </td>
    <td>
      12-12-1555
    </td>
    <td>
      12-12-1555
    </td>
    <td>
      adsfasdfasdlfasd;klfj askdljf al;skdjf la;skdjf ;lkasdfj;alksdjf klasdjfl;kasdjf;lak sdjfasjflaskdjf ;slkdjfas;lkdjf
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    
  </tbody>
     </table>
  
</body>
</html>
```